# missing "const" leading to "error: no matching function for call to"

Tags: c++

I have a class ssyvector like this:

```
class ssyvector {
public :
  ssyvector( ssyvector& a);
```

It have a constructor that accept a reference to another ssyvector.

I further define an operator+ like this

```
ssyvector operator+(const ssyvector& a,const ssyvector& b)
```

I try to apply this operator to two ssyvectors like this:

```
ssyvector c10000 = s10000+a10000;
```

Then g++ complain that :

```
main.cpp:31:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘Ssyvector::ssyvector::ssyvector(Ssyvector::ssyvector)’
  ssyvector c10000 = s10000+a10000;
                            ^
```

I can remove this error by add "const" keyword to definition of constructor like this:

```
class ssyvector {
public :
  ssyvector( const ssyvector& a);
```

It seems so confusing, can someone explain this?
Thanks

Comment: Your operator+() returns an rvalue, you cant bind an rvalue (i.e. temporary object) to a non-const reference. Which means your copy ctor needs to take a const ref (as it should)

Comment: so const XX is not a special XX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `operator+` is returning a temporary object. You can only take const references to temporary objects.

Also your constructor should take a const reference, since making a copy of something shouldn't change the thing being copied (unless we get into quantum mechanics...)

Comment: so const XX is not a special XX?

Comment: The const keyword means the object won't change, and that you can only call const methods on it.